# magento pagination for ul li tag

Tags: magento-1.9, php, pagination

i am working with magento(1.9), the pagination is not properly working for ul li tag.

```
**code in phtml file**

<?php $collection =  $this->getCollection(); ?>
<div class="article_page"> 
    <div class="article_left_coloum">
        <div class="article_page_title">
            <h1>Articles</h1> 
        </div>
            <?php if($collection->getCount()) {
                foreach($collection as $_collection) { ?>
                    <div class="article_page_listing">              
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <?php if($_collection->getImagePath()!='') {
                                    $image = explode("/",$_collection->getImagePath());
                                    $image_name = array_pop($image);
                                    $image_path =  implode("/",$image);
                                    $image = Mage::helper('flphotos')->resizeImage($image_name, 140,140, $image_path);
                                }  ?>
                                <img src="" alt="">
                            <div class="article_page_listing_left">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image ; ?>" width="140" height="140">
                            </div>

                            <div class="ariticle_page_listing_right">
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('article/article/detail',array('_query'=>array('id'=>Mage::helper('flphotos')->Encrypt($_collection->getArticleId())))); ?>" title="Title"><?php echo $_collection->getTitle() ; ?></a>
                                <span> 
                                    <?php echo $_collection->getDescription() ?>                                
                                </span>
                                <div class="ariticle_page_listing_right_bottom">
                                    <p class="list_hart_icon">   </p>  
                                    <p> <span><?php echo $_collection->getLikeCount(); ?></span><?php echo $this->__('Likes'); ?></p> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php } } echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
    </div>

**code is block file**

protected function _getArticleModel() {
        return Mage::getModel('flarticle/article');
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = $this->_getArticleModel()->getAllArticle($this->getRequest()->getParam('userid'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }
```

**Mysql image**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

define this function    `$pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());` you are calling this but not define it..

```
public function getCollection()     
         {             
            $limit        =    12;
            $curr_page    =    1;

            if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p'))
            {
                $curr_page    =    Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p');
            }
    if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))
            {
                $limit    =    Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('limit');
            }
            //Calculate Offset    
            $offset     =    ($curr_page - 1) * $limit;
                $checkin=$this->getdatasotre();


            $collection    =    Mage::getModel('modulename/test')->getCollection()



                                                        ;

            $collection->getSelect()->limit($limit,$offset);

            return $collection;
        }
```